# PHP form keep values of form when reload or go to previous

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, local-storage

My problem is that I want to remember values of my form after submitting it.
Let me explain:
My form looks like this:

```
<fieldset>
<legend> Indicateur : </legend>
<select name="indicateur" id="indicateur" onchange="choixindic(this.value);" >
<option value="indic1">Indic1</option>
<option value="indic2">Indic2</option>
<option value="indic3">Indic3</option>
<option value="indic4">Indic4</option>
<option value="indic5">Indic5</option>

</select>
</fieldset>
<br>

<fieldset>
<legend> Catégorie : </legend>
<div>
<table >
<tr>
<td><div class="part">
<input type="checkbox" id="part" name="part"><label for="part">Particuliers</label>
</div></td>
<td><div class="pro">
<input type="checkbox" id="pro" name="pro"><label for="pro">Petits Pros</label>
</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

So i have 2 input types, that is to say a **select** and 2 **checkboxes**.

Then I submit the form and go to "main.php" to see the result (plot of performance indicators with highcharts)

But when i click previous to go back to my form, the latter is empty, and my choices are gone (if I checked "pros", when I come back no checkbox is checked)

My header looks like this , maybe some js scripts are in cause:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>OTIS</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="testform.css">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptSat.js"></script>
<script src="js/Respond-Master/Respond-Master/dest/respond.min.js"></script>

<script>


</script>
</head>
```

**My Question is**

How to keep values after an user Action ?

Comment: Best of all you use SESSIONS for that: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 1):

You could use the example of @siha or you just pass them to your sessions variable. which i preffer

Comment: Okay I stored all the values in $SESSION variable, but then how can I fill my form with those data ?

Comment: `<input value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name'] ?>"></>` Just basic php var echo in html :)

Comment: for example if <input type="checkbox" id="pro" name="pro"> is checked by the user, then I do $_SESSION['formvalues']['pro']=$_POST['pro'].
Then how can I say to the input type checkbox that I want it to be checked when I click previous ? 
<input type="checkbox" id="pro" name="pro" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['formvalues']['pro'] ?> "> will not work I think

Comment: It's ok i figured it out :)  Here is what I did :
 <input type="checkbox" id="pro" name="pro" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['formvalues']['pro'])) echo "checked"; ?> >
Thanks all

Comment: Could you please assign the answer so further readers know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following suggestion.

When the user visits the your page and submits the form, you save all the values of the form into a localStorage with html5.

**Store when form is submitted**

```
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
localStorage.setItem("choice", "1");
```

When the user re-visits your page, you have to check if the items you have saved exist. If they do not, the values will return null.

However, if they do, you can populate your fields in this manner.

**Check and retrieve when form is visited**

```
var lastname = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
if(lastname != null) { document.getElementById("result").innerHTML(lastname); }
```

Do remember to remove your items at any point when you do not need them anymore. That will ensure that your user will have a clean form when they expect it to be.

Comment: if js is disabled, that is not going to work. session is a better idea I think.

Comment: @ksno yeah that is true. i was answering according to his tags